# When does a Mordell curve have non-trivial torsion?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, mordell-curves

Is there a known simple criteria for when a Mordell curve has non-trivial torsion?

A comment in this question: 
[Family of elliptic curves with trivial torsion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400382/family-of-elliptic-curves-with-trivial-torsion)
Suggests that
$$y^2 = x^3 + k$$
has nontrivial torsion when k is 1, a square, or a cube.

If this is true, it would be nice to see it explained or point to a reference I can read more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a further reference, extending the result you have linked.

**Theorem:** If $k$ is square-free and not equal to $1$, the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3+k$ has no rational torsion points.

*Proof:* See A. Knapp, Elliptic Curves, Princeton Univ. Press, 1992, Theorem $5.3$.

More generally, there is indeed a classification result as follows.

**Theorem:** Let $k=m^6 \cdot k_0$, where $m, k_0\in \Bbb Z$ and $k_0$ is free of sixth power prime factors. Then the torsion subgroup of $E\colon y^2=x^3+k$ over $\Bbb Q$ is given as follows:
$$
E_{\rm tors}(\Bbb Q)=
\begin{cases}
\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z & \text{ if } k_0= 1, \\
\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z & \text{ if $k_0$ is a square diﬀerent from $1$}, \\
\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z & \text{ if $k_0=−432$}, \\
\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z & \text{ if $k_0$ is a cube diﬀerent from $1$}, \\
\{\mathcal O\}  & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Is there something that explains what makes -432 so very special here? Is it related to the birational mapping to $u^3 + v^3 = 1$?

Comment: Yes, $-432=-27\cdot 16$ is related to the discriminant of the Mordell curve. For $k=-432m^6$, the torsion points are $\mathcal{O},(12m^2,\pm 36m^3)$.